# PHP Echo Form Action URL Issue

Tags: php

I have this code:

```
echo " <form action='https://test.com/forum/index.php?/search/&q=". 
$row['record_meta_keywords'] ." 
&type=cms_records7&search_and_or=and&search_in=titles'> ";
echo " <select  name='/search/&q=". $row['record_meta_keywords'] ." 
&type=cms_records7&search_and_or=and&search_in=titles'> ";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<option value='" . $row['record_meta_keywords'] ."'>" . 
$row['record_meta_keywords'] ."</option>";
}
echo " </select> ";
echo " <br><br> ";
echo " <input type='submit'> ";
echo " </form> ";
?>
```

But, when I choose an option in the dropdown, the URL is being displayed like this:

> https://test.com/forum/index.php?search=%26q%3DHowell+Lanes+%26type%3Dcms_records7%26search_and_or%3Dand%26search_in%3Dtitles

The problem is I need the URL to be displayed like this in order for it to work properly:

> https://test.com/forum/index.php?/search/&q=Howell%20Lanes%20&type=cms_records7&search_and_or=and&search_in=titles

I tried urlencode but that didn't seem to work either.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: That code could not produce that output. Your PHP specifically contains the string `index.php?/search/` which does not appear in your output.

Comment: You need to use `htmlspecialchars` for output, you need to use `http_build_query` to build query strings, and if you want your code to be readable, you need to not mix your HTML and PHP so terribly.

Comment: Can somoene please help me with the code?  My PHP skills aren't as advanced.  I tried using htmlspecialchars but that didn't work.